# Probability Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

In a telephone exchange, it is believed that the durations of calls are exponentially distributed with mean length 10 min. Three calls start simultaneously at 1:00:00 PM; assume that the duration of these calls are independent.

i) What is the probability that the longest call last beyond 1:15:00 PM. hint: under what circumstances are all calls finished by 1:15:00PM.

ii) Suppose that the second longest call ends at 1:08:30 PM, what is the probability that the longest call is still going on at 1:23:30 PM

I have started answering the problem in the following way:

Xi - exponential(lambda i)
for i = 1, 2, … n.
and X1, …, Xn mutually independent r.v.
then min{X1,…,Xn} follows Exp(Σ lambda i)

So the for the shortest call to last beyond 1:15:00 pm, I would have:

Z = X1 + X2 + X3
Z - Exp(3*1/10) = Exp(3/10)

P(Z  > 15) = 1 - P(Z < 15) = e^(-15*3/10)

However, this leads to the minimum, not the maximum.

I am kind of stuck here.

Can anyone give me a path for a solution ?

Comment: If there was only one call, the can you work out the probability that it lasts for at least 15 minutes?  And then, could you work out the probability that it lasted less than 15 minutes, and further, can you do that for all 3 of 3 calls ending in less than 3 minutes?

Comment: @5xum sorry I flag the comment, I just wanted to say that I edit the problem with my approach

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda = 1/10 = 0.1$

> i) What is the probability that the longest call last beyond 1:15:00 PM. hint: under what circumstances are all calls finished by 1:15:00PM.

Any of the calls could be the longest one.

Exponential cdf is $1- exp(-\lambda*x)$.

So the probability that the longest call last beyond 1:15:00 PM = probability that at least one of the calls is longer than 15 mins = $(1 -exp(-0.1*15))^2*exp(-0.1*15) + (1-exp(-0.1*15)) *exp(-0.1*15)^2 +  exp(-0.1*15)^3$

> ii) Suppose that the second longest call ends at 1:08:30 PM, what is the probability that the longest call is still going on at 1:23:30 PM

As the calls are independent.

probability that longest call is longer than 23.5 minutes = $(exp(-0.1*23.5))$ = 0.095

probability that the second longest call and least longest calls are less than 8.5 minutes = $(1 - exp(-0.1*8.5))^2$

So the joint probability = $(1 - exp(-0.1*8.5))^2*(exp(-0.1*23.5)) $